# ng-disabled on anchor inside <li>

Tags: html, angularjs

How can I disable drop down menu item that uses ui-router and looks like this?

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a ui-sref="state.random">A random state</a></li>
</ul>
```

obviously this doesn't work:

```
<li ng-disabled="true"><a ui-sref="state.random">A random state</a></li>
```

nor this:

```
<li><a ui-sref="state.random" ng-disabled="true">A random state</a></li>
```

Comment: You could always add a class attribute and use some CSS

Comment: can you provide an example? @Und3rTow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ng-disabled`  don't work on the `li` tag. Need to do this using css styles.

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events:none; //This makes it not clickable
    opacity:0.6;         //This grays it out to look disabled
}

<li class="disabled"><a ui-sref="state.random">A random state</a></li>
```

Comment: I realize now that my question was wrong but i used your answer as a part of my solution. Your answer combined with this solved it: ```<li ng-class="{'disabled': licences.read == false}">``` Thank you!

Comment: @Mangs make it little more compact `<li ng-class="{'disabled': !licences.read}">`

Answer (score 2):

Disabling might not work here. You may have to use a ternary operator with ui-sref. As I assume disabling would be conditional. The disabled style effect can be introduced with CSS.

```js
$scope.someValue = false;
```

```html
<li><a ui-sref={{someValue ? 'state.random' : ''}}>A random state</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem (angular 2), here is what worked for me:

HTML file:

```
<li (click)="onClick(item, $event)"
  tooltip="{{isItemDisabled() ? getText(item.tooltipText) : undefined}}">
  <a href="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"
       [ngClass]="{'disabled': isItemDisabled()}"
       id="btnSelect{{getMenuLabel(tabitem)}}">{{getMenuLabel(tabitem)}}</a>
</li>
```

TS file:

```
onClick(isItemDisabled, $event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  if (!isItemDisabled) {
    // do whatever
  }
}
```

CSS file:

```
disabled {
 opacity: 0.6;
 cursor: not-allowed;
 pointer-events: none;
}
```